# Change CodeIgniter session config based on user selection

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm trying to implement a "remember me" checkbox in my login form. Looking at the Docs I see that I can change the config setting by default:

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 10; // I set it to 10 seconds for testing
```

What I'm trying to do is extend this time indefinitely, or much longer at least, if the user checks a box. I am changing the value of `sess_expiration` when the input is passed via the POST, and I can see that the value is changed, but it still expires after the default time, not after the new time.

```
if ( $this->input->post('rememberMe') )
{
    $this->config->set_item('sess_expiration', 0);
}
```

Just before I set the session information I call this and if I echo it out I see the value is properly set, but I wait and then my session is gone and I am redirected back to my login page.

```
$this->session->set_userdata(
    array('user' => array(
        'userId' => $user->userId,
        'userName' => $user->userName,
        'userLevel' => $user->userLevel,
        'userEmail' => $user->userEmail,
        'userCreated' => $user->userCreated,
        'userUpdated' => $user->userUpdated,
        'userStatus' => $user->userStatus
    ),
    'loggedIn' => $user->userId
));
```

Am I doing this wrong? I'm spending too much time on this issue so I'll move on and hope someone here can point out what I'm doing poorly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about setting a cookie for this? I think you're better off storing the data with the user, so each time they return their cookie data can be searched for the variable you define.

```
if ( $this->input->post('rememberMe') )   
{   
    $this->input->set_cookie($name, $value, $expire, $domain, $path, $prefix, $secure);
}
```

If you don't want to use the variables you can pass an array with the information instead. Once you've done that, pick a name for the cookie and set the Username in the $value, or whatever you want, and then in the controller for your login page look for the cookie:

```
if($this->input->get_cookie('cookie_name'))
{
   //set the username and password for your form
}
else
{
  //No cookie was found. Don't set anything.
}
```

I don't have time this morning to test this out, but it should work for you.

Comment: My ability to over complicate a simple solution amazes me at times. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
// Change the config setting
$this->config->set_item('sess_expiration',0);

// Force the Session class to recapture global settings by calling it's constructor
$this->session->CI_Session()
```

Comment: When I run the `CI_Session()` code is breaks my auth controller. Should I be setting the `$user` session information first or after I call the `CI_Session()` function? I can't find it documented in the user guide.